# Spring Integration Java DSL and Http.outboundGateway: How to get the real error message JSON

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

How to get the real error message JSON when the  `Http.outboundGateway` call is failed.

For example my program does the `HTTP POST`. The operation fails with the error code `400 Bad Request` and the real error message is (tested with the Postman):

```
{
  "name": [
    "This field is needed."
  ]
}
```

I have the error channel like this:

```
    @Bean
    private IntegrationFlow myErrorChannel() {
      return f -> f.handle("myErrorHandler", "handle")
      ....
      ;
    }
```

and the Class `MyErrorHandler` is like this:

```
@Service
public class MyErrorHandler {
   @ServiceActivator
   public Message<MessageHandlingException> handle(Message<MessageHandlingException> message) {
      ...
   }
```

}

Does the `MessageHandlingException` contain the real error message?

```
    {
      "name": [
          "This field is needed."
      ]
    }
```

I debugged the code and checked the `MessageHandlingException` exception and it seems it doesn't contain the real error message. The detailMessage contains the text `400 Bad Request`, but I want to know the real error message.

How to get the real error message?

Edit:

This is working (I'm assigning the real error message to the new payload):

```
        final RestClientResponseException clientException = (RestClientResponseException) messagingHandlingException.getCause();
        payload = clientException.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Resttemplate` uses a `DefaultResponseErrorHandler` by default. That one has a logic like:

```
protected void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response, HttpStatus statusCode) throws IOException {
    String statusText = response.getStatusText();
    HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
    byte[] body = getResponseBody(response);
    Charset charset = getCharset(response);
    switch (statusCode.series()) {
        case CLIENT_ERROR:
            throw HttpClientErrorException.create(statusCode, statusText, headers, body, charset);
        case SERVER_ERROR:
            throw HttpServerErrorException.create(statusCode, statusText, headers, body, charset);
        default:
            throw new UnknownHttpStatusCodeException(statusCode.value(), statusText, headers, body, charset);
    }
}
```

An exception from here is thrown to the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` which really wraps it into the `MessageHandlingException`.

Since you say that you can handle the last one via your `MyErrorHandler`, I would suggest you just take a look into the `cause` of the `MessageHandlingException`, and you'll that `RestClientResponseException` with all the required info from the response.

Comment: I checked with debugger and then logged message.getPayload().getMostSpecificCause(), but the result is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request. It is not what I wanted. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: And also I can see from the complete stack trace that there is not the information what I need. Is there something wrong I'm doing??

Comment: I think the information you need is indeed not included into stack trace, but that is a part of getters on the `RestClientResponseException`

Comment: Thanks, just you said. Added the answer above.